# SQL Server 2012 Express prerequisites Error in visual studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, setup-project

I am trying to make a setup file for my WPF Project using "Setup Project", But I get the following errors when trying to build the project:

> ERROR: To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'SqlExpress2012\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.EXE' for item 'SQL Server 2012 Express' to your local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=616018.
>
> ERROR: To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'SqlExpress2012\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.EXE' for item 'SQL Server 2012 Express' to your local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=616018.

Although I've downloaded and moved these files to Packages folder, it still gets this error. (I had the same problem with .Net Framework 4.6.1 prerequisites , after moving downloaded files to to the Packages folder, problem was fixed)

Answer (score 0):

**I can't post a comment** yet, so I will just answer.

There are many questions on stackoverflow that can help you with your problem:

[ClickOnce cannot find its prerequisites while the files are at the place they have to be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276876/clickonce-cannot-find-its-prerequisites-while-the-files-are-at-the-place-they-ha?rq=1) <--This one is marked as answered

[cannot put prerquisite components in the same location as my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25673797/cannot-put-prerquisite-components-in-the-same-location-as-my-application?rq=1)

[Error while setting Sql Express 2012 as prerequisite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30356873/error-while-setting-sql-express-2012-as-prerequisite?rq=1)

---

Hope it helps